# Using the proof for NP-hardness for another problem

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

I already asked similar question [here.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/123811/validity-of-a-simple-polynomial-time-reduction) However, now I restate the question. Let say that $P$ is an NP-hard optimization problem and $Q$ is a problem with unknown complexity. Additionally, we have an algorithm for solving problem $Q$. We can solve problem $P$ with input $x$ in the following manner:

```
    max = -inf - the optimal value for P 
    n = size of x
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
         val = solveQ(x, i)
         if (val > max) max = val
```

This is an oracle reduction, and therefore it does not follow that $Q$ is NP-hard, but that $P$ is Turing reducible to $Q$.

I found the proof that $P$ is at least weakly NP-hard. The proof uses many-one reduction from the
weakly NP-complete problem $R$. For each instance $y$ of $R$ there exist polynomial-time algorithm which transforms it to instance $x$ of $P$. Instance of $R$ is positive iff $P$ instance obtained using the transformation has a solution with =1.

Incidentally, I noticed that instance $x$ is always 
an instance of $Q$ with $i = 2$. To clarify, algorithm transforms any $R$ instance $y$ to $P$ instance $x$, which corresponds to $Q$ instance $z = (x, 2)$.

At this point, can we claim that $Q$ is at least weakly NP-hard?

Comment: Since $P$ and $Q$ are optimization problems, there's no such thing as Yes/No instances for them. Are you thinking of particular decision versions of $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: Yes, probably should restate that. Instance of $R$ is positive iff $P$ or $Q$ instance obtained using the transformation has a solution with $max = 1$.

Comment: As to obtain the answer for an instance of R, we need to solve P and we do so by invoking oracle for Q once, I concluded that the Q is at least weakly NP-hard.